# How do i make stuff render through glass? (Cycles)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, glass

i've got into back blender a few days ago. I tried making a Volvo 850r, but when i added glass (with Glass BSDF) nothing renders through it, not even lights. How would i solve it? For reference there are two point lights in headlights (if that makes sense). Also there is one light in the interior for testing. Thanks in advance for help! :)[image: My model of Volvo 850r]

Comment: See if [this](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/optimizations/reducing_noise.html#glass-and-transparent-shadows) section from the Blender manual helps.